# Is Intersection Observer API the only way to animate on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, intersection-observer

I came across at a lot of this websites which have animations that get triggered throught the scroll. I actually at first thought we did it in javascript by calculating the position of the cursor relative to the website page we can through animations at each positions.

But when I did a bit of googling I found this stuff about Intersection Observer. Is there are any performance issue or something of sort to my visioned method?

**NB:** I am looking for a way to do it without a framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the Intersection Observer API you would listen for the `scroll` event and check the position of the elements with each scrolled pixel. That is performance heavy work and gets called a lot! Intersection Observers are designed to tackle this issue in a performant way. You won't get better performance from an alternative.

You don't need a framework. The API is native to your browser (considering you have support).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for ready to use animations, then [AOS](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) library is a good example. There are lots of other libraries for animating on scroll.